# Need a simple PHP framework for my webapp

Tags: php

Can anyone suggest me a nice and simple framework for PHP ?

I have tested CodeIgniter and it seems simple. I have been reading about CakePhp, but it seems a bit more complicated than CI. Maybe there are other nice frameworks that could be worth looking at?

Answer (score 48):

I am the creator of a small framework named [Laravel](http://laravel.com). It is RESTful by design, extremely simple, and has great documentation.

Other features include a beautifully simple ORM and session / cache drivers.